# How can I write this C# Z-axis vector rotation in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, c#, xna

I have written a very simple XNA game in C# that uses the following method to rotationally alter projectiles as they fly towards a target. The objective of this is to make the projectiles somewhat 'homing':

```
float rotation;
Vector2 velocity;
int speed;

public void SetRotation(float value) // Make the projectiles homing
{
    rotation = value;

    velocity = Vector2.Transform(new Vector2(0, -speed),
            Matrix.CreateRotationZ(rotation));
}
```

I am trying (for my own learning purposes - I am very new to JavaScript) to port my game to JavaScript and allow it to be played inside a canvas. Could anyone suggest how I could re-write the above method as a JS function?

As someone who is a complete beginner to JavaScript would this most easily be done using an existing framework of some kind?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method of rotating a vector involves some basic matrix math. (Please forgive the ASCII art. No LaTeX makes this more difficult)

First represent the vector in homogenous-coordinate form:

```
    [ x ]
v = | y |
    | z |
    [ 1 ]
```

The rotation matrix is provided by:

```
    [ cos(r)  -sin(r)  0  0 ]
M = | sin(r)   cos(r)  0  0 |
    |  0        0      1  0 |
    [  0        0      1  1 ]
```

Where `r` is the amount of rotation about `Z`

To apply the transformation, multiply the matrix `M` by the vector `v`:

```
          [ cos(r)  -sin(r)  0  0 ]   [ x ]
v' = Mv = | sin(r)   cos(r)  0  0 | * | y |
          |  0        0      1  0 |   | z |
          [  0        0      0  1 ]   [ 1 ]
```

Simplifying the multiplication gives the formula

```
v' = { x' = x * cos(r) - y * sin(r)
     { y' = x * sin(r) + y * cos(r)
     { z' = z
```

(Note: in Javascript, the `sin()` and `cos()` functions take arguments in radians.)

Comment: Perfect, brings back memories of my astrophysics degree. Should be a simple case of using the simplified matrix and making sure to convert to radians if required.